# How to guarantee a monitor never leaves fullscreen mode?

Tags: fullscreen, direct3d

One of my monitors (there will be at least three monitors on the machine) needs stay in fullscreen mode for some presentation work, and cannot afford losing the fullscreen state no matter what.

The problem is I found there are many way to drag that monitor back to windowed mode: show desktop button, window + d, window + tab, etc.

Is there a simple way to make sure one monitor stay in fullscreen mode? If not, what is the practical way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... currently I've removed all input devices and control the software remotely from another computer...

Answer (score 1):

When creating device you are required to provide behavior flags:

```
HRESULT CreateDevice(
  [in]           UINT Adapter,
  [in]           D3DDEVTYPE DeviceType,
  [in]           HWND hFocusWindow,
  [in]           DWORD BehaviorFlags,
  [in, out]      D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS *pPresentationParameters,
  [out, retval]  IDirect3DDevice9 **ppReturnedDeviceInterface
);
```

Choose the following one: `D3DCREATE_NOWINDOWCHANGES`. This way you instruct Windows to not mangle your window size and focus. Note that in this mode you must handle all the events including Alt+Tab and size events if your application rely on them (many frameworks do).

You also may want specifying flag `D3DCREATE_DISABLE_PRINTSCREEN` since some screen capturers may pop up a window.

Comment: All those flags were already set. The actual problem is that when I do something said above(and moving a window to that monitor works, too), the fullscreened window will be put into a occluded state and leave fullscreen mode.